# Strange Cookie Issue in Android WebView?

Tags: android, asp.net, android-webview

I have native application in Andriod and Iphone with ASP.NET as a back-end. I am sending request to my ASP.NET server API by appending Session_Id cookie using HttpClient classes which works great. But I also need to send the same session in WebView. The problem is that some times WebView send the Session_Id cookie and sometimes doesn't. It strange for me. I am not able to find why sometimes webview send the cookie and sometimes doesn't. Here is my code,

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  myapp = ((....) getApplicationContext());
  setTimeout(true);
  try {
   getActionBarHelper().setupHomeActivity();

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  webView = new CustomWebView(this, this);
  webView.getWebView().addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "android");
  getTimeDiff();

  if(MyApplication.INSTANCE.isLoggedin()){
    Cookie sessionCookie = MyApplication.INSTANCE.getCookie();

    List<Cookie> cookies = MyApplication.INSTANCE.getClient().getCookieStore().getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
        sessionCookie = cookies.get(i);
    }

  try{
    if(sessionCookie!=null){

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        if (sessionCookie != null) {
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
            String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName() + "="
                    + sessionCookie.getValue() + "; domain="
                    + sessionCookie.getDomain();

            if (MyApplication.isDebug())

            cookieManager.setCookie(sessionCookie.getDomain(),(sessionCookie.getName() + "=" + sessionCookie.getValue()));
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }else{
    if (MyApplication.isDebug())
        Log.d("WebView", " Cookie is null: " );
    }
    }else{
    if (MyApplication.isDebug())
        Log.d("WebView", " Cookie is null: " );
    }
  }catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  Log.e("WenView", "============================ ");

  }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop appears to only include the single line that retrieves the cookie... so your logic that's setting the cookie below only gets called once, with whatever the last cookie happened to be.  Since the cookies aren't ordered in the list, this probably explains why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't; it's working when your cookie is last, and failing otherwise.

The answer is to just expand your for loop to include ALL the logic underneath as well.  Your copying code looks fine, and I expect it is if you can get it to work sometimes.